# "position: absolute" in a child doesn't work if body has perspective

Tags: css, css-transitions, transform, webkit-perspective

I faced a problem while building a simple CSS transition.

I have my `body` element which its only child is a `div` with position absolute.

Inside the `div` I inserted a rectangle with a simple 3d transition on the *hover* pseudoclass: `transform: rotateX(90deg)`, and I want to set a `perspective` style in the parent element in order to make it appear better.

When I set a `perspective` in the body the transition works properly: it creates the perspective effect and it looks good. But -and the problem is here- the child loses the absolute position (at least in Chrome).

I created a [codepen example](https://codepen.io/crisz/pen/WZmOZa), you can comment the `body` style out and this will apply an absolute position.

When the `perspective` is set the `div` also loses its blue background, but I think this happens because its height becomes 0.

Is it a bug? How can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: why not try applying the perspective to the absolute positioned div (child of body) instead of applying to the body itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into this exact same issue, very weird behavior. Adding perspective to the body introduces weird quirks, my approach was to create a virtual 'body' container inside the  to act as if it were the body.

Instead of something like

```
<html>
  <body style="perspective: 1000px">
    <div style="transform:rotate(10deg); position:absolute"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

try

```
<html>
  <body>
    <container style="perspective: 1000px">
      <div style="transform:rotate(10deg); position:absolute"></div>
    </container>
  </body>
</html>
```